# ViewController's title disappears unexpectedly

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having some problems with my ViewController's title. The structure is as following: `UINavigationController > UITabBarController > UIViewController/UITableViewController`

This is a screenrecording of the buggy behaviour: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzjcbwbcqw3y9xl/Screen%20Recording%202020-09-17%20at%2021.53.13.mov?dl=0

These are the options I've set up in Storyboards:
[image]
[image]

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Why is your root VC of type `UINavigationController`? If you're using a `UITabBarController`, you will usually want that to be your root VC. Then, you can fill the `UITabBarController` with views of type `UINavigationCointroller`. So, your structure should be, `UITabBarController` > `UINavigationController` > `UIViewController`/`UITableViewController`.

Comment: Hi @gmdev, the UINavigagionController is the root VC because it is used for the login/signup process as well. I’m not using any tab bars there. Should I change it?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to change it. Your structure could potentially be `UINavigationController`>`UITabBarController`>`UINavigationController`>`UIViewController`/`UITableViewController`

Answer (score 0):

From your video, it looks like you have two main screens that the user can navigate to and from via the tab bar.

Now, inside of the `UITabBarController`, instead of just adding a `UIViewController`, add a `UINavigationController` with the root VC of whichever `UIViewController` you want to show.

The structure of your `UITabBarController` could look something like this:
[image: structure diagram]

This way, you can set the title of the green and orange view controllers to whatever you want. I hope this helps, let me know if any issues arise.